# Windows oriented setup to deploy one file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I would like to build a setup, or something like that (1 file), to deliver a single file to a target system. Plugin for an application, installable to users AppData folder.

After some research I'm still not sure in which direction to look. I can create the setup project with Visual Studio 2010, but all of the options so far seem to be way too heavy or have some flaws.

SetupProject stubbornly wants to create an application folder which I don't need, and complains about installation to user folder. Cab doesn't seem to offer automatic install, oneclick is not available for the project, etc.

Is there an easier setup technology I could use?

Requirements:

- Install -> Copy 1 file to a folder
  under %userprofile%\3rdpartyapp\ if
  it exists (xcopy).
- Uninstall -> Delete the file and also
  one folder with custom settings
  (rmdir \s).
- Distribution -> Free for commercial
  use.

Maybe I should just pack the file in self extracting c++ exe?

Comment: You'll have one problem with the uninstall, and that's removal of the folder with custom settings if they're made by the user. Installers don't typically remove anything they didn't install (because users get ticked off when you delete their personal data or documents, and you can't tell what they've created in the folder). So deleting the folder if it's not empty after removing what the installer created is not usually allowable.

Comment: The folder is created by 3rdpartyapp on behalf of my plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It may be overkill for one file, but I like [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/) for creating setup packages. Check it out, and see if it suits you. It is very easy to use and deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WiX toolset](http://Look%20at%20%5BWiX%20toolset%5D%5B1%5D.%20It%20allows%20creating%20MSI-based%20installers,%20and%20the%20installer%20could%20be). It allows creating MSI-based installers, and the installer could be quite simple:

1. Search for %userprofile%\3rdpartyapp;
2. Copy the file into it, if it exists;
3. Fail install or maybe create it, if it does not exist.

Uninstall would be very simple: it would need to remove the installed file. To remove a subfolder of 3rdpartyapp, you can use [RemoveFolderEx](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_removefolderex.htm) element.

MSI registers the installed app with Add/Remove Programs Control panel. Uninstall is handled by Windows Installer service, therefore you don't need to copy any additional files or programs to support uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

I think any setup technology is too heavy for one file. I'd go with creating a simple application that would extract the file from its resources stream and copy it into %userprofile%\3rdpartyapp.

Uninstall is trickier: there should be something that can handle the uninstall process. It could be a batch or script (js, vbs) file stored somewhere in user's profile, another simple application or the same one. (Installation process can also be handled with a script.)